# Does the phrase "violations will be enforced" make any sense?

Tags: meaning, signage

I see this on traffic signs around my town, and I don't think it makes any sense.  I googled the phrase and apparently, a lot of people use it that way, but that does not change my opinion.

I think you can:
Enforce a law
Respond to a violation
Punish a violator

But how can you enforce a violation?  Violations are prohibited… not enforced.

Comment: To me it means that if you commit a violation then the law will be enforced.

Comment: I am sure that is what the sign writers wanted to say.  I don't think the words they chose work the way they used them.

Comment: Unless 'Violations' is the name of the relevent section in the rule book.

Comment: It can't mean what it doesn't, can it?

Comment: It should be *sense* in the title.

Comment: Do you think anyone fails to understand what these signs intend?

Comment: Are these roads signs? If they are, then on the most important words have been written so that when you seen them you don't need to 'read' them as such and so your brain fills in the relevant grammar in a way that you still understand its meaning.

Another example would be 'SLOW', by itself it doesn't make much sense, but when you see it at speed you instantly understand the meaning in this context and start to reduce your speed. At least you should anyway.

Comment: @GEdgar It's possible, since 75% of this city speaks English as a 2nd language.  Your point is taken; most people probably do get the meaning.  But the same meaning can by conveyed using the CORRECT words.

Comment: @KrisQuigley It's a sign on a road, but it's about panhandling in the medians so it is most likely not directed at actual drivers.  Regardless, even if it was for drivers, there are four words used, and I can certainly think of other four-word combos that would convey the same message but without the problem of using words in ways they weren't intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enforce means to impose or make effective. eg, enforce silence, enforce a law.

So, no, you cannot enforce violations (unless if you are suggesting that people are compelled to make violations).

Comment: This answer is technically correct. Let's consider not only definition, but connotation. The sign writer wanted the reader to consider their own potential violation, then consider the law being enforced. The sign gets its point across.

Answer (score -2):

Very similar to Oklahoma’s signs on the Turnpike: “Failure to pay toll strictly enforced.”
They replaced them. No legal defense for “that’s what we meant.”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *No legal defense for “that’s what we meant.”* That's untrue. It may apply to contracts in some cases but a questionably worded sign does not invalidate a toll applied and enforced in numerous other ways. "Shoplifting laws strictly enforced" wouldn't make it legal to steal from a shop, and the same principle applies. "Failure to pay toll strictly enforced" doesn't create an offense of failing to pay a toll; the offense is created by legislation and other signage that says "toll zone", "toll road", etc. If you want legal justification, take it to Law SE.